# Question about a section of a novel

Tags: translation

I have come across this section of a light novel, and am having trouble translating it to English. I think there are a few references that don't translate well, and I cannot find an explanation for the references. From what I can gather, it is a male character who is coming to feed a prisoner who is trying to seduce him. Can anyone help with explaining these:

Prisoner: “아이야. 더 가까이 오지 않으련? 내가 천상을 보여 줄게.”

Main Character: “크롸롸 아스카. 우에하라 노인.”

Prisoner: “……응?”

Main Character: “대륙은 섬나라에 비하면 아직 멀었다. 헛소리 그만하고 밥이나 처먹도록.”

Prisoner: “얘, 얘! 야, 이 자라 새끼야!”

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I interpret it.  Not sure about 크롸롸 아스카 but it doesn't sound like anything important.

> Prisoner: Hey kid, why don't you come closer? I'll show you the
> heavenly world.
>
> Main Character: Croira, Aska, old man Uehara.  (크롸롸 아스카 might be a
> made-up expletive - never heard of it before)
>
> Prisoner: What ...?
>
> Main Character: The mainland has a long ways to go to catch up with
> the island nation.  Why don't you stop talking nonsense and stuff
> yourself with the food.
>
> Prisoner: Hey, hey, kid! You terrapin shit!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Tony's answer, there are several Korean slang, too.

- 크롸롸 아스카 and 우에하라 노인 seem to be parodies of 키라라 아스카 (Kirara Asuka) and 우에하라 아이 (Uehara Ai), both of who are famous Japanese adult actresses in Korea. Here, 노인 (senior) was used as an antonym of 아이 (kid).
- The mainland (대륙), the peninsula (반도), and the island (섬 or 열도) are Internet slang sometimes used to refer to China, Korea, and Japan, respectively. I guess the man/woman seducing the main character is Chinese. Japanese adult video industry is much more developed and popular than that in Korea or China, so the main character meant that watching a Japan pornography would feel better than making out with the prisoner.
- Terrapin is a really rarely used slang that means a buried penis. The prisoner mentioned it to belittle the main character's sexual ability, but many native Koreans will not understand its meaning either.